# Drive Letter and multiple drives

Tags: hard-drive, drive-letter

I have multiple drives with different types of files on them. I need to swap them in and out of my computer from time to time.

My question is will I benefit from setting specific drive letters on each of the HDDs and will Windows 10 maintain the drive letter for each drive as I swap them? I've run into problems where I get an error message that I cannot access the drive I need becasue of drive letter conflict.

Comment: Internal or external disks?

Answer (score 2):

I am not running Windows 10 but since Windows XP Microsoft kept track of drive letter use at least until Windows 7.

Unfortunately you have successfully hidden the number of disks/volumes and the number of free drive letters.

As you are already experiencing conflict issues you should consider using mount points within Windows Disk Management instead of using up scarce drive letters.

You could create empty folders like
C:\Drive1
C:\Drive2
C:\Drive3 ....

and assign each disk to such a folder. That will make the content of your disk/volume appear in the selected folder and you should get rid of assignment conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Registry:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\MountedDevices

Windows keeps track of its drive letters here.
As long as the drive matches the signature, it should retain its letter.

[image]